# What day of the week was Yeziyat Mizrayim?

Tags: mesorah-tradition, yetziat-mitzrayim

Do we have a tradition what day of the week Yeziayit Mizrayim was?   I seem to recall seeing it stated somewhere, but a quick search didn't find any sources.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [Seder Olam Rabbah 5](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Seder_Olam_Rabbah.5.2?lang=bi), it was on a **Friday**:

> ממחרת הפסח, ערב שבת היה, נסעו מרעמסס, שנאמר ויסעו בני ישראל מרעמסס סכתה, וכתיב ויסעו מרעמסס בחדש הראשון בחמשה עשר יום לחדש
>
> The day after [offering] the Pesach, which was a Friday, they journeyed from Ra'meses, as it says, "The Children of Israel journeyed from Ra'meses to Sukkot", and it is written, "And they journeyed from Ra'meses in the First Month, on the fifteenth day of the month."

However, according to other tannaitic opinions quoted in [Shabbat 87b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shabbat.87b.2?lang=bi), the fifteenth of Nissan was actually a **Thursday**:

> נִיסָן שֶׁבּוֹ יָצְאוּ יִשְׂרָאֵל מִמִּצְרַיִם, בְּאַרְבָּעָה עָשָׂר שָׁחֲטוּ פִּסְחֵיהֶם, וּבַחֲמִשָּׁה עָשָׂר יָצְאוּ ... וְאוֹתוֹ הַיּוֹם חֲמִישִׁי בַּשַּׁבָּת הָיָה.‏
>
> Nissan in which Israel left Egypt: on the fourteenth they slaughtered their Pesach, and on the fifteenth they left ... and that day was a Thursday.

Comment: It is worthwhile to note that many explain that the latter midrashic opinion is accepted in regards to the widespread explanation of the miracle which occured on Shabbat Hagadol, supposedly the 10th of Nissan that year.